# What is the best way to link an SVG image?

Tags: html, image, svg

I just wanted to know what is the best way (best practice) to insert an SVG image to an HTML.

Way 1: SVG inside the HTML

```
    <picture class="triangle-icon">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="100">
        <path d="M 95,50 5,95 5,5 z"></path>
      </svg>
    </picture>
```

Way 2: Linking the SVG image

```
<img src="../../../public/svg/svg-triangle.svg" alt="triangle icon">
```

Way 3: else better than way 1 or 2!

I'm asking this because I don't know if is correct to put the SVG images in the HTML because some SVG images are quite long codes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best way" depends on the specifics of your use case.  Therefore, I'm not going to tell you what to do, but will give you information on how to decide:

When you inline:

- The SVG data is included in the page, so no extra HTTP request is made to get that SVG.
- If you re-use SVGs on multiple pages, you're sending that data for the image each time.
- When there is a cache miss for the page, you're sending that data again for the SVG, even if it could have been cached.
- If your pages are generated dynamically server-side, the page itself won't be cached client-side, therefore your SVGs aren't cached either and have to be loaded each time.

When you use the `src` attribute:

- An extra HTTP request is made for each resource.
- Your SVGs can be cached *independent of the page*.  Therefore, the images are cached for different pages, and when your pages change.

With all that in mind, I would only inline the SVGs if you're only using them on a single static page that doesn't change frequently.  Otherwise, leave them separate.

Comment: Wow! thanks for the explanation and your time! I really appreciate. Will keep your cases in mind to decide if inline or src and SVG.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend adding them using `src`. This is how most libraries do it (example: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome). It also allows you to host these assets on a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

Answer (score 1):

If you have many small svg files, then I recommend you to inline them, to avoid making too many requests to the server.

The larger images should only be linked, so the user's browser can cache them.

Comment: Just what I want to avoid! I have several SVGs in an HTML file and it makes it almost infinite! Thanks.